# Show Hide multiple Divs only one at a time - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, user-interface, show-hide

I'm making a little app, there's a sidebar menu and a header menu, and I basically want all items in both menus to show/hide content on one "page"/window. So when one button is clicked it shows the appropriate Div and hides all others, etc.

```
<a id="linktodiv1">Show Window 1, hide other windows</a>
<a id="linktodiv2">Show Window 2, hide other windows</a>
<a id="linktodiv3">Show Window 3, hide other windows</a>
<div id="linktodiv4">Show Window 4, hide other windows</div>

<div id="window1">content</div>
<div id="window2">content</div>
<div id="window3">content</div>
<div id="window4">content</div>
```

Any idea what the best/cleanest way to code that using Jquery? Thanks so much for any help.

Comment: Put the divs into a container div and hide the container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can use indexing assuming they all stay in 1:1 order in page

```
var $links = $('[id^=linktodiv]'),// cache elements to variables
    $content = $('[id^=window]');

$links.click(function(){
    // hide all content, show matching index content window
    $content.hide().eq( $links.index(this) ).show();        
});
```

Will be very helpful to give each common component a common class

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/usgww64d/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

Give your links and divs classes. E.g. `.showHide` for links and `.contDiv` for divs. Assuming they have the same order:

```
$('.showHide').on('click', function() {
    $('.contDiv').hide('slow');
    $('.contDiv').eq($(this).index()).show('slow');
});
```

[**jsfiddle DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/ycs1aq0s/)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following jquery `accordion` method as part of the jquery UI library - https://jqueryui.com/accordion/  - very clean and exactly what you are looking for I believe

http://jsfiddle.net/d6mSA/616/

The code you would need is

```
    <div id="accordion"> 
    <h3><a href="#">Show Window 1</a></h3>
    <div>
        <p>Section 1 Content</p>
    </div>
        <h3><a href="#">Show Window 2</a></h3>
    <div>
        <p>Section 2 Content</div>
        <h3><a href="#">Show Window 3</a></h3>
    <div>
        <p>Section 3 Content</p>
    </div>
        <h3><a href="#">Show Window 4</a></h3>
    <div>
        <p>Section 4 Content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(function () {
    $("#accordion").accordion({
        autoHeight: true
    });
    $("#accordion").accordion({
        collapsible: true
    });
});
```

Comment: Accordion is more for displaying a list of content based on clicks on their headings. I think the OP is really looking for tabs: https://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for tabs. If you're loading bootstrap on the page you can use this:

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs

If you already have jQuery UI (or you are willing to load it) you can use this:

https://jqueryui.com/tabs/

If you don't have either but are willing to pull in a plugin something like this will work:

http://os.alfajango.com/easytabs/
http://stitchui.com/lightweight-jquery-tab-plugin/